# Chat message in Django-Channel not broadcasting

Tags: python, django, django-channels, channel

I am working with django-channels. I created a consumer to broadcast a message. The strange thing is that after opening 2 windows to see the broadcast, the below happens.

The message is displayed on the last refreshed window (the number of message coincides with number of windows opened). But the message never gets to displayed on the other windows.

channels==3.0.3

channels-redis==3.2.0

Django==3.2.3

Below is my consumer.py

```
class EchoBroadcastConsumer(SyncConsumer):

def websocket_connect(self, event):
    self.room_name = 'broadcast'
    self.send({
        'type': 'websocket.accept',
    })
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(self.room_name, self.channel_name)
    print(f'[{self.channel_name}] - You are connected!')

def websocket_receive(self, event):
    print(f'[{self.channel_name}]- You are have received {event["text"]}')
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_name,
        {
            'type': 'websocket.message',
            'text': event.get('text')
        }
    )

def websocket_message(self, event):
    print(f'[{self.channel_name}] - Message Sent {event["text"]}')
    self.send({
        'type': 'websocket.send',
        'text': event.get('text')
    })

def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
    print(f'[{self.channel_name}] - You are have Disconnected')
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(self.room_name, self.channel_name)
```

Below is my frontend (JS)

```
const url = 'ws:127.0.0.1:8000/ws' + window.location.pathname;
const ws = new WebSocket(url);

ws.onopen = function(event){
    console.log("Connection is Open");
}

ws.onmessage = function(event){
    console.log("Message is received");
    const ul = document.getElementById('chat_list');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.append(document.createTextNode(event.data));
    ul.append(li);
   // var data = JSON.parse(event.data)
    //li.append(document.createTextNode(
     //   '['+ data.username+ ']:' + data.text
    //));
    ul.append(li);
}

ws.onclose = function(event){
    console.log("Connection is Closed");
}

ws.onerror = function(event){
    console.log("Something went wrong");
}

const message_form = document.getElementById('message_form');
message_form.addEventListener('submit', sendMessage);

function sendMessage(e){
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault()
    ws.send(document.getElementById('chat_text').value);
    message_form.reset();
    return false;
```

Below is my routing.py

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

from chat.consumers import EchoConsumer, EchoBroadcastConsumer, ChatConsumer

    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                
                path('ws/chat/<str:username>/', EchoBroadcastConsumer()),
                
            ]))
    })
```

Below is a screenshot; I opened two windows but got the message on one window and it's a duplicated.

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution ?